# Error 80096005 from signtool -- how am I signing wrong?

Tags: windows, signtool

I'm trying to sign an executable. The command line I'm using to sign is `signtool sign -fd SHA256 -tr http://freetsa.org/tsr -td SHA256`.

Running `signtool verify -v -pa` claims that the timestamp is malformed:

```
SignTool Warning: An error has been found with the timestamp.
    CERT_TRUST_STATUS.dwErrorStatus: 0x00000020
    CERT_TRUST_STATUS.dwInfoStatus: 0x00000020
SignTool Error: WinVerifyTrust returned error: 0x80096005
    The timestamp signature and/or certificate could not be verified or is malformed.
```

Running `signtool verify -v` claims instead that the root cert isn't trusted:

```
SignTool Warning: An error has been found with the timestamp.
    CERT_TRUST_STATUS.dwErrorStatus: 0x00000020
    CERT_TRUST_STATUS.dwInfoStatus: 0x00000020
SignTool Error: A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root
    certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider.
```

The root certificate in question is:

```
    Issued to: AAA Certificate Services
    Issued by: AAA Certificate Services
    Expires:   Sun Dec 31 16:59:59 2028¹
    SHA1 Hash: D1EB23A46D17D68FD92564C2F1F1601764D8E349
```

¹ I'm not sure why this particular time. If it's in local time, that's 2100 UTC. If it's in local time corrected for DST, it's 2200. Not that this makes a difference.

Anyway, I checked the trusted certificates. The root certificate in question is, in fact, trusted by the computer.

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem is that `freetsa.org` isn't actually signing its timestamp. Switching servers fixed the problem.